Cannot use multiple .env in node.js
Im trying to use 3 different file,

.env, using PORT=80
.env.staging, using PORT=8080
.env.dev, using PORT=3030

my server.js is as such
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cors from 'cors';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

const nodeEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
dotenv.config({ path: `.env.${nodeEnv}` });
console.log(`Loaded environment variables for ${process.env.NODE_ENV}:`);

const { PORT } = process.env;

mongoose.connect(MONGO_URL)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
    app.listen(PORT, '0.0.0.0', () => {
      console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error connecting to MongoDB:', error);
  });

and my package.json
  "scripts": {
    "start-prod": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
    "start-staging": "NODE_ENV=staging node server.js",
    "start-dev": "NODE_ENV=dev node server.js"
  },

Whatever the start I do, the first console.log return dev, staging or prod, but the 2nd console log for PORT will always return 80 (value for PORT in .env)
So it's always .env that is taken into account.
I tried at least 10 different combinations found on stack overflow. After some test if I change .env for .env.prod for exemple everything break because no environnement variable is taken into account which makes me think that the .env.staging and .env.dev are just not existent when I run them on the terminal.
Another strange point, I'm coding on VS code and
.env has dark blue const name and white value,
.env.staging / .env.dev had light blue or yellow const name and orange values.
If anyone has a solution it would help a lot.
Thank you

Why aren't you just setting actual env vars in those environments?

I also tried, each environments had a NODE_ENV in it, it did not work either

No, I mean just set PORT etc. The point of .env files is to simulate locally what you actually have in production environments.

oh no no its an exemple I have around 10 more var based on different deployement with different api endpoints, passwords, keys, but I have a console.log on PORT to make it easy to debug

Try using the absolute path instead of the relative one in case the working directory doesn't contain the .env files e.g. dotenv.config({ path: \${__dirname}/.env.${nodeEnv}` }). Also if you use NODE_ENV=productionyou need a.env.productionfile for production and your.env` file doesn't seem to be used at all

Right, and you set all of those in those environments, as actual env vars. Then just use .env locally. Otherwise you have to manage multiple files containing secrets from various environments, which isn't secure at all.

This is depending on your deployment. But you should have,
For example: you have 3 environment files:
.env.prod
.env.staging
.env.dev

When you start environment, you should, create a new .env file. By default, It will pick .env file for build application.
"scripts": {
    "start-prod": "cp .env.prod .env && NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
    "start-staging": "cp .env.staging .env NODE_ENV=staging node server.js",
    "start-dev": "cp .env.dev .env && NODE_ENV=dev node server.js"
  },

Hope this help.
